# how to remove no file selected and place the file name which is uploaded successfully using jquery in input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am uploading a file using servlet and once it is successfull shows a message "Upload success".

But once upload is done the filename next to input file shows "no file selected".

I need to show the file name once upload is success in input type file.

How to do it using jquery/javascript

Comment: <input id="image" type="file" name="image">

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
```

after choose, or better after click upload as a first action.

Comment: on click of browse i get the filename next to browse button but once upload is done the file name is not there it comes as "No file selectd"

Comment: it depends on the way you upload it, if its ajax call then it should stay as a variable. If you reload page you can reload it with data in url (like: upload.php?file=filename) or store this data in sesion. Ah and first of all - hide the borwsers upload button and replace it with your own - cause you could not change the default browsers button data. @user2585622

Comment: ok but once i get the file name in session how to remove "no file selected " and replace with filename in jqueery/javascript

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to replace the original one with custom. @user2585622

Comment: not able to understand once upload is success need the filename